# find & validate a string in a string

Tags: php, regex

I need to find a number inside a filename.

Filename example:

```
_x1984x_testfile.jpg
```

I need to extract the string between "*x" and "x*" brackets (only if it is at the start of the filename)

Then check if the string is a number and return the result if it is.
With the example above, the code should return 1984

How can i do that ?

Comment: What do you mean *only if its at the start of the filename?* `x` is the second character here and the number is the third so neither of them are at the start of the filename?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No regex needed:

```
$v = explode('x',$string);
if( $v[0] == '_' && is_numeric($v[1]) ) $result = $v[1];
```

...
You could also use a different `if` condition like [strlen()](https://www.php.net/strlen) if you're not happy with my assumptions here. This approach will be much faster than using regex.

Comment: Why this solution us upvoted? >> http://ideone.com/BaM90L

Comment: Works fine:http://ideone.com/tc7Zhc

Comment: OP wants :: **Then check if the string is a number and return the result if it is**

Comment: Okay - updated answer to make it explicit

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_match("/^_x(\d+)x_/", '_x1984x_testfile.jpg', $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Comment: Wrong output >> http://ideone.com/wLbf7a

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_match("/(?<=^_x)\d+(?=x_)/", '_x1984x_testfile.jpg', $m);
print $m[0];
```

See demo **[here](http://ideone.com/yzSqe0)**.